# Expected number of trials for event X to happen for the first time vs number of trials after which the expected number of times X happens is 1.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Are these two quantities always the same? Can anyone provide a proof/explanation or counter-example?

As an example, let a trial consist choosing a number from the set {1,2,...,n}, and let event X be that a number is chosen that has been chosen before (a duplicate). Is it true that the expected number of picks for the first duplicate to occur, is the same as the number of picks whereby the expected number of duplicates after this number of picks is 1?

My intuition is that they are the same, and I hope this isn't a daft question.

Many thanks,

t-tough

edit:

Counterexample! Suppose buses always turn up on the hour and suppose exactly half the buses all turn up together at 4pm, and the other half all turn up together at 6pm, but this partition is done at random. Consider the event that bus X turns up. Then the expected number of hours after noon for bus X to turn up for the first time is 5. But at 5pm the expected number of times that bus X has turned up is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I don't understand what the last part means.  What is, "the number of picks whereby the expected number of duplicates after this number of picks is 1?"  How many picks will there be altogether?  If you keep picking, the expected number of duplicates goes to infinity.

Comment: After say m picks, there will be an expected number of duplicates. If we pick m such that this expectation is 1, then is this the expected number of picks required to achieve first duplicate?

Comment: This is not clear at all.  If you have a memory less process, like tossing a fair coin repeatedly, then there is never a moment at which the "expected number of trials to success is $1$."  If, say, you are waiting for the first $H$, then the expected number of tosses is always $2$, no matter how often you have tossed in the past.

Comment: Now I understand.  I think it's just two ways of saying the same thing, and I guess it's obvious that I find the first way easier to understand.

Comment: @lulu I think the OP is talking about the aggregate number of duplicates that have occurred so far.

Comment: @saulspatz  I;'m just trying to parse the question in the header.  Is the question meant to be general or does it only apply to the context spelled out in the body?

Comment: @saulspatz  For the question in the body, the only way that the expected number of trials to the first duplicate  is $1$ is if you have drawn all the options exactly once, a highly improbable state to reach (trusting that $n$ is large).

Comment: @lulu Personally, I think that the OP means the expected number of trials until the first duplicate occurs, and the question in the body is an awkward attempt to state that differently.  He's talking about the number of duplicates that have occurred in the past, not how long we have to wait until we see another duplicate.  Of course, there isn't an integral number of trials where the expected number of duplicates is $1$, so I think he's talking about the expectation.

Comment: Yes saulspatz your last post is correct. Do you have a definitive answer and could you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a fairly deep question! There is something called the "Markov property" which you should look into if you are really interested. I have taken this question to ask if expected value is "memoryless" as in it the time you must wait for the first time $X$ to happen is the time you must wait for it to happen again after it has happened. I.E if you are waiting for busses and you arrive just after one bus has left is this the same wait you would have had to endure if you arrived just after the second bus leaves?

Anyways the answer is: $\textbf{"It depends on the distribution"}$ I can think of lots of examples where it is yes and lots where it is no. Lets explore some together:

$\textbf{Yes:}$

1. You toss a fair coin until you get a head.
2. An ant, who starts at the bottom left corner, walks randomly on the 6 sides of hexagon until it reaches its starting corner.
3. You play poker until you are dealt pocket aces (a pair of aces when you are given only 2 cards).
4. You wait on train until someone whose name starts with Z comes onboard.
5. You generate numbers randomly from $1-100$ until you get a prime.

$\textbf{No:}$

1. You toss coins until the sequence "HHH" appears
2. An ant, who starts at the bottom left corner, walks randomly on the 6 sides of hexagon until it reaches the corner diagonally opposite
3. You deal cards (without replacement from a standard deck) until you get an Ace
4. You wait on train until you meet a teenager.
5. You generate numbers randomly from $1-100$ until you get a prime but delete every even number and keep every odd number you have generated.

Now let us examine them: In the yes pile numbers $1,3,4,5$ all are examples such that when we succeed we have not effected our chances of future success. I.E tossing a  head makes another head no more or less likely. Or when we are dealt aces in one hand then the next time the cards are shuffled and re-dealt we are just as likely to get aces. Example 2 is a little different and fun because it effectively is an example of when the game "restarts" i.e once the ant is at the bottom corner the game begins again and it wanders until it has reached the bottom corner.

In the no pile we see that success might impair future sucess. For example in 4) we might note that teenagers tend to come in groups and as such if we see 1 teenager we might be more likely to see another one very quickly, his brother, classmate or friend might be with him and as such seeing a child might make it more likely to see another one quickly and as such reduce the expected waiting time.  In example 1) we can note that once we have tossed "HHH" we need only toss 1 more head for another run of "HHH" and as such tossing 3 heads in a row makes it easier and quicker to toss another "3 Heads", in reality yes this is simply the last two heads and one more but note that the sequence "HHHH" has 2 different runs of 3 heads. I will leave you to think about why in  2) 3) and 5) success either makes future success more or less likely to happen and as such effects the expected value.

Comment: Thanks Oskar, much appreciated. I understand that if the probability of a success doesn't change from trial to trial, then the expected number of trials to first success is the same as the number of trials needed whereby the expected number of past successes is 1. Both turn out to be 1/p, where p is the probability of a success. Are you saying that when p is not fixed, that is the probability of a success changes depending on past trials, then the two things are not necessarily the same? Or perhaps necessarily not the same?! Can you give an intuitive reason for why?

Comment: I've posted a counterexample on the original post, which gives a nice feel for why. Would be great to hear your thoughts.

Comment: What is your interpretation of the “expected value “ of a random variable , and then as such “the expected value until success “ thinking about what these quantities are asking will be helpful. I am struggling to understand your example of busses . All your maths is perfect but it doesn’t seem to be about your query.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the trials are independent and equally likely, the answer is yes.  If the event in question has probability $p$, then the expected number of trials until the first occurrence is $1/p$ (the expectation of a geometric distribution).  On the other hand, the expected number of successes in $m$ trials is $mp$ (the expectation of a binomial distribution), so you need $m = 1/p$ trials to have an expectation of $1$ success.

In the example you give, however, these conditions obviously don't hold, so it's harder to tell.  In particular I'm not sure how to get an expression for $\mathbb{E}$(number of duplicates after $m$ trials) as a function of $m$.

EDIT: Based on computer simulations I suspect the answer is no.  You can calculate directly
$$
\mathbb{E}(\text{# of trials until first duplicate}) = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{10} + 3\cdot \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{2}{10} + \dots + 11 \cdot \frac{9}{10} \dots \frac{2}{10} \frac{1}{10} \approx 4.66,
$$
but simulations indicate that the expected number of duplicates after $5$ trials is $\approx 0.9$.

Comment: Thank you Adam. Very intruiging to me as to why these two aren't neccessarily the same. I understand that it's not so easy to come up with a closed expression for either quanities in the example I gave, but still working on an intuitive justification for why these don't have to coincide. Very useful to run a computer simulation, for insight into the true nature of things.

Comment: I've posted a counterexample on the original post, which gives a nice feel for why. Would be great to hear your thoughts

Comment: @t-tough I agree that's a counterexample